# Umbraco 7 + Razor: How to get a Document/Node by ID?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

In the sample code, this is how you get the Home page from a .cshtml file

```
var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
```

Now, how do I get a specific page/node (not related to current page, eg. the News page) by its ID?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use exactly the same approach but use `.Where(x => x.Id == newsPageId)`.

Alternatively, you can use `@Umbraco.TypedContent(newsPageId)` or `@Umbraco.Content(newsPageId)`.

Comment: You're right but the question specifically states Razor and a .cshtml file. If you need answer from another context, ask a question :)

Answer (score 8):

The direct answer is Umbraco.TypedContent(id).But! If you want to get the "News" node from anywhere, I reccomend the following. Using ids is problematic for some  multilingual setups and also if the id changes it will stop working.

```
// 1- Get root node
var site = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Site");

// 2- Get news node
var news = site.Descendant("News");
```

This approach is more dynamic and you can now use your news node to loop it's children, or whatever you need. For this, you do need specific document types setup for Site and News types.

Hope this helps!